# Ubuntu freezes without doing anything

Tags: 14.04, kernel, gui, freeze

I just started Ubuntu and after a minute it froze. Nothing works, mouse, terminal, GUI, nothing. How am I supposed to solve this problem which I have never faced before?

This is the error message shown in virtual terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have a problem with your disk drive sda1. It's formatted as an ext4 file system and the file system is spitting out errors.

Probably one way of fixing it would be by copying as much data as you can from the drive and then discarding the drive and putting the data on another one. Expensive and time-consuming. You can try other things, and then YMMV.

Another approach would be to try and fix the disk errors using a program like fsck. Just google "using fsck to fix disc errors" is probably the quickest way to proceed if you decide to go down that route. The risk (perhaps small) is that the drive will continue to fail and you may lose more data. On the other hand it's not abnormal for drives to fail slowly and in a controlled manner.

What you do next probably depends a lot on how important the data on the drive is, whether or not it has been backed up, how much there is, whether you can afford any system down time etc etc.

Comment: Actually I tried both and neither of them worked, Previously I was using Kernel4.0.2 So I jumped down to 3.1.6 assuming kernel was the reason for error. Also This is second time I reinstalled Ubuntu14.04. and still I am getting error. And I did tried to fix errors from recovery mode and fsck but its always the same.

Comment: If it's not the drive then I suppose it could be a hardware issue :-/ so you might want to post details about what hardware you're using, but I'm definitely out of my depth if unmounting the drive and running fsck on it (to mark the bad sectors as bad) doesn't fix the problem.